# How much actual computer mathematics programs can be done in this extremely weak concrete set theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computational-mathematics, alternative-set-theories

I'm interested in the strength of this theory, and in particular if it can be a theory in which all computer programming of mathematics (which I assume them to be ultra-finite proximate kinds of formalization since we cannot have an actual infinite set of inputs in actual computer programs) can be founded.

CONCRETE SET THEORY

*language:* first order logic with membership symbol added as a extra-logical primitive two place relation symbol $``\in"$, and another extra-logical primitive two place relation symbol of "equality" $``="$.

*Extra-logical Axioms:*

**Equality axioms:**
$ x=x \\ x=y \to \forall a [x=a \to y=a] \\ x=y \to \forall a [x \in a \to y \in a] \\ x=y \to \forall a [a \in x \to a \in y]$

*Membership axioms:*

**Extensionality:** $\forall x,y [\forall z( z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y]$

**Concrete set construction:** if $n=0,1,2,3,...$, then: $$\forall x_1,..,x_n \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y=x_1 \lor ...\lor y=x_n)$$; is an axiom.

Comment: At a glance, I suspect that this theory is decidable.

Comment: even if so, what kind of mathematics can be programmed in this decidable theory? I mean actually programmed.

Comment: What does it mean to program mathematics inside a theory?

Comment: I meant of course parts of mathematics, like some parts of arithmetic, like summation up to certain big finite number, or division approximated to some specified n_th digit, something that make computers calculate. Matters like those. We know that computer programs cannot capture infinity in an actual manner, so they would approximate matters.

Comment: I still don't know what it means to "program" *any* piece of math inside a theory, especially if the theory is quite weak.

Comment: how computer programs are working. they must work on concrete object aren't they.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by **programming** some piece of math in a **theory**. This is all quite unclear to me.

Comment: how do computers calculate, how do they measure areas, etc.. all of these are mathematical programs aren't they?

Comment: I still have no idea how that relates to "programming" something inside a theory, or indeed what precisely you mean. Until you can make this precise, I give up.

Comment: I said in which all *actual* computer programming parts of mathematics can be *founded*, it means *interpreted*, for example computers can calculate 1+1=2 , 2+1=3, etc... for a finite string of numerals, and this apparently can be done in the above theory. You can take for example the first 1000 sets that are iterated singletons of the empty set, define successor relation on them by being a singleton, then define anterior sets of them by closure under predecession, etc.. then we can define summation by 1 up to 1000, and other summation operators, etc.. all these can be done here.

Comment: what I mean is simply can this theory achieve everything that an actual computer program can achieve.